# What is better to get the right type of an image file? $image['type'] or $image ['mime']?

Tags: php, image, types, mime

I'm having a problem with detecting the right type of an image file. Using $image['type'] gives me: image/jpeg, but If I use $image['mime'] It gives me: image/webp.

I need to detect the right type of the image so I can upload it to my server.

Which one shoud I use and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Which one shoud I use and why?"_ - that question is of course currently impossible for us to answer, because you did not explain where $image is supposed to come from in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe It comes from a form using POST method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are unreliable. Because both rely on data specified by logic outside your own control: the file name extension based approach *obviously* is unreliable, since anyone can specify whatever "dot something" he/she wants to append to a file name. And the mime type indication is set by the client side, so it depends on a variety of aspects and can easily be spoofed too.

The best bet would be to use the server side OS capabilities to actually test the *content* of the file instead of relying on data provided by others. SO for example the `file` command under typical Linux based systems.

The question I'd like to ask back, meant as a thought for you to re-think your approach: *why* do you need to detect that? Why is that required? Why can't you simply accept whatever the client side uploads (with size limits applied)?

Comment: Because I'm only proccesing 2 types of images by using: imagecreatefromjpeg or imagecreatefrompng, that's why I need to detect rightly If the type of image is image/jpeg or image/png. In other cases (gif, webp,etc.), I would reject them.

Comment: @Eduardo Why can't you simply try to process the uploaded files and handle any failure accordingly? That saves you from having to invest into an additional type detecting logic that is unreliable per definition anyway.